# How many sets in the power set containing a given integer?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{J}\equiv \{1,...,J\}$ and let $\mathcal{C}$ be the power set of $\mathcal{J}$ (with cardinality $2^{J}$).

**Question:** take any $j\in \mathcal{J}$. How many elements of $\mathcal{C}$ (sets) contain $j$?

For example: if $J=3$ and $j=1$, then $\mathcal{C}\equiv \Big\{\emptyset, \{1,2,3\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}\Big\}$ and there are $4$ sets in $\mathcal{C}$ containing $1$.

Comment: Now try with $J=4,5,\ldots$ and look for a pattern.

Comment: In the same way that you count how many sets there are in the power set in the first place, use the exact same method to count here.  For example by the rule of product.  The only difference is that when you reach the $j$'th element, you no longer have two choices (include or not include) you only have one choice as you *must* include it.  You still have two choices for every *other* element though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: each set containing $j$ can be paired nicely with a certain set not containing $j$ and vice versa, so the answer is "half of them".

Answer (score 3):

Can you find a bijective function that maps each element of the power set of $\mathcal{J}-\{j\}$ to the set that you want to count?

Answer (score 1):

> Let $\mathcal{J}\equiv \{1,...,J\}$ and let $\mathcal{C}$ be the power set of $\mathcal{J}$ (with cardinality $2^{J}$).

The *reason* the cardinality of $\mathcal{C}$ is $2^{J}$ is that for each element you will have a set of subsets in $\mathcal{C}$ without some given element $a$ and another, otherwise identical set of subsets that do contain $a$. This applies to each member of $\mathcal{J}$ giving the multiplication of the $2$ states (present/absent) for each base set element in the powerset elements, hence $2^{J}$ cardinality.